# How to change mysql date format using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date-format

I am developing a website using CI and mysql. i want to change date format from yyyy-mm-dd into dd-mm-yyyy. I know that i should use date_format function. But when I try to use it, it didn't work-the date format didn't change. Also i've try to add 2nd parameter(FALSE). but, I also found problem with that, especially, when i need to query more than 1 column. Here is my code:

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->table = array(
        'name'      => 'article',
        'coloumn'   => array(
            'article_id',
            'article_title',
            'article_content',
            'article_summary',
            'date_format(article_publishdate, \'%d-%M-%Y %H:%i:%s\') as article_publishdate',
            'article_source',
            'article_link',
            'media_type',
            'media_link',
            'media_position',
            'article_category.category_title',
        ),
        'join'      =>  array(
                            0 => array('article_category' , 'article.article_category_id=article_category.category_id', 'left'),
                        ),    
        'where'     => array(),    
        'order'     => array(),
        'limit'     => array(),
        'idkey'     => 'article_id',
    );  
}

public function getfullbody($id)
{
    $this->db->query("update article set article_view = (article_view+1) where article_id = '$id'");
    $this->db->select($this->table['column'], FALSE);
        if (count($this->table['join'])>0){
            foreach ($this->table['join'] as $row):
                if (!empty($row[2])){
                    $this->db->join($row[0], $row[1], $row[2]);
                }
                else {
                    $this->db->join($row[0], $row[1]);
                }
            endforeach;
        }

    $this->db->where("article_id = '$id'");
    $query = $this->db->get($this->table['name']);
    $data = $query;
    return $data;
}
```

Problem: when i use date_format() with codeigniter, it didn't change the date format.
Then, how to fixed it? Thank you.

Comment: What happened when you use date_format? That has worked like charm for me every time. There is some mistake in format like you want month in mm format but you are using M which returns month name. Please refer this once again. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: when i use with CI, the function didn't change the format. but when i use it without CI, it's work.

Comment: You've got a typo.. you define `$this->table['coloumn']` instead of `$this->table['column']`

Answer (score 1):

Change coloumn to column index and if you want to show date as dd-mm-yyyy use this below code

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->table = array(
        'name'      => 'article',
        'column'   => array(
            'article_id',
            'article_title',
            'article_content',
            'article_summary',
            'date_format(article_publishdate, \'%d-%m-%Y\') as article_publishdate',
            'article_source',
            'article_link',
            'media_type',
            'media_link',
            'media_position',
            'article_category.category_title',
        ),
        'join'      =>  array(
                            0 => array('article_category' , 'article.article_category_id=article_category.category_id', 'left'),
                        ),    
        'where'     => array(),    
        'order'     => array(),
        'limit'     => array(),
        'idkey'     => 'article_id',
    );  
}

public function getfullbody($id)
{
    $this->db->query("update article set article_view = (article_view+1) where article_id = '$id'");
    $this->db->select($this->table['column'], FALSE);
        if (count($this->table['join'])>0){
            foreach ($this->table['join'] as $row):
                if (!empty($row[2])){
                    $this->db->join($row[0], $row[1], $row[2]);
                }
                else {
                    $this->db->join($row[0], $row[1]);
                }
            endforeach;
        }

    $this->db->where("article_id = '$id'");
    $query = $this->db->get($this->table['name']);
    $data = $query;
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Test on Code igniter 2...

```
('%d-%m-%Y')
```

in your coude

```
"date_format(article_publishdate, ('%d-%m-%Y')) as article_publishdate",
```

it's work very weel for me